# iText 7 Text Watermark annotation not recognized by Adobe Reader - uneditable text

Tags: c#, pdf, annotations, itext7, watermark

I am able to add and remove a page header using a text watermark annotation using itext 7 and C#. I am able to see and print the PDF via Adobe Acrobat Reader. @remy

However, I am unable to use Adobe Acrobat Pro DC to remove the pager header. When I do a search and replace, it says text is un-editable.

The PDF files are located here: [PDF Files Original, With Watermark Step2 and WaterMark Removed Step3](https://github.com/nicholsf/itext7PDFHdrWaterMarkAnnotCsharp/tree/master/PDFUpdater2Itext7/PDFUpdater/PDF)

```
    public static string CompanyName= "ACME77";
    public static string AnnotName = CompanyName + "WatermarkHDR";

    public byte[] Add(string infile, string outFile)
    {
        PdfFont baseFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD, Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName, false);
        Rectangle pageSize;
        string NoOfPagesPadded = string.Empty;
        string PageNoPadded = string.Empty;
        string HdrLeft = string.Empty;
        string HdrRight = string.Empty;

        int xLeft = 30;
        int xRight = 110;  //was 100
        int xTop = 30;

        float watermarkTrimmingRectangleWidth;  //= 300;
        float watermarkTrimmingRectangleHeight = 300; 

        float formXOffset = 0;  
        float formYOffset = -5;  // was zero  set to -5 because dangling letters (e.g. g) were being cut-off
        byte[] outByteFile;
        byte[] inByteFile = null;

        try
        {
            inByteFile = File.ReadAllBytes(infile);
            IRandomAccessSource inSourceFile = new RandomAccessSourceFactory().CreateSource(inByteFile);
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inSourceFile, new ReaderProperties()).SetUnethicalReading(true))
            {
                using (var outMemoryFile = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (PdfWriter pdfWrite = new PdfWriter(outMemoryFile))
                    {
                        using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, pdfWrite))
                        {
                            using (Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc))
                            {
                                int n = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();

                                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                                {
                                    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
                                    pageSize = page.GetMediaBox();

                                    watermarkTrimmingRectangleWidth = pageSize.GetWidth();
                                    float PageWidth = pageSize.GetWidth();
                                    float PageHeight = pageSize.GetHeight();
                                    int rotation = page.GetRotation();
                                    Rectangle watermarkTrimmingRectangle = new Rectangle(pageSize.GetLeft() + xLeft, pageSize.GetTop() - xTop, watermarkTrimmingRectangleWidth, watermarkTrimmingRectangleHeight);

                                    PdfWatermarkAnnotation watermark = new PdfWatermarkAnnotation(watermarkTrimmingRectangle);

                                    watermark.SetName(new PdfString(AnnotName));
                                    Rectangle formRectangle = new Rectangle(formXOffset, formYOffset, watermarkTrimmingRectangleWidth, watermarkTrimmingRectangleHeight);

                                    PdfFormXObject form = new PdfFormXObject(formRectangle);   //Observation: font XObject will be resized to fit inside the watermark rectangle.  If it is larger, your text will be stretched.
                                    PdfCanvas canvasOver = new PdfCanvas(form, pdfDoc);

                                    canvasOver.SetFillColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.RED);
                                    canvasOver.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 10);
                                    canvasOver.SaveState();

                                    string SDSNo = "z2345678";
                                    HdrLeft = CompanyName + $" SDS# {SDSNo}";
                                     NoOfPagesPadded = (n.ToString());
                                    PageNoPadded = i.ToString();
                                    HdrRight = $"Page {PageNoPadded} of {NoOfPagesPadded}";
                                    canvasOver.BeginText()
                                              .SetColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.RED, true)
                                              .SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 10)
                                              .ShowText(HdrLeft)
                                              .EndText();
                                    canvasOver.BeginText()
                                              .MoveText(formRectangle.GetRight() - xRight, 0)
                                              .SetColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.RED, true)
                                              .SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 10)
                                              .ShowText(HdrRight)                                                  
                                              .EndText();
                                    canvasOver.SaveState();

                                    canvasOver.RestoreState();
                                    canvasOver.Release();

                                    watermark.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, new PdfAnnotationAppearance(form.GetPdfObject()));
                                    watermark.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);

                                    page.AddAnnotation(watermark);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        outByteFile = outMemoryFile.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(outFile, outByteFile);

        }    
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.ToString());
            return inByteFile;
            throw;
        }
        return outByteFile;
    } 

    public void RemovetWatermarkPDF(string sourceFile, string destinationPath)
    {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFile), new PdfWriter(destinationPath));
        var numberOfPages = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();

        for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
        {
            // PdfAnnotation 
            PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfDoc.GetPage(i).GetPdfObject();
            PdfArray annots = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.Annots);
            for (int j = 0; j < annots.Size(); j++)
            {
                PdfDictionary annotation = annots.GetAsDictionary(j);
                if (PdfName.Watermark.Equals(annotation.GetAsName(PdfName.Subtype)))
                {
                    string x = annotation.GetAsString(PdfName.NM).GetValue();
                    if (x == AnnotName)
                    {
                        annotation.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        pdfDoc.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like an Adobe Acrobat issue. The pdf specification allows many ways to create the same effect, and Adobe Acrobat foremost allows *editing* of structures if they are implemented as (or similar to how) Acrobat would have done it.

Comment: How can this be confirmed that is a Adobe Acrobat Issue?

Comment: First of all one should ask oneself whether this is an issue at all. Does Adobe Acrobat promise to be able to edit all text? Apparently it considers some kind of text uneditable but does not call it broken or invalid. Thus, unless it promises to be able to edit arbitrary texts, this actually is no issue at all. If it promises so, though, you have what appears at first glance to be an Acrobat issue. Thus, why do you think that the text must not be considered uneditable by Acrobat?