# How to allow 2nd signer to put watermark after 1st signer signed?

Tags: itext7

How to put a watermark after 1st signer signed a PDF?

I have a multiple signers case:

- Signer 1 already signed and I set the CertificationLevel to 3
- Signer 2 put watermark into that PDF, I do the following process flow:
- Prepare PDF that already signed by signer 1 (prepared_for2.pdf)
- inject the 2nd signer p7s into prepared_for2.pdf

it looks like only commentting, form fill-in, signing, page adding action are allowed..

is there any way to allow the 2nd signer put watermark (ie. decline image) into a PDF after the 1st signer signed?

Need help

many thanks in advance

Regards
Don

Comment: Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16711745/1729265) for allowed and disallowed changes to a signed PDF. Essentially changes to the static page content never are allowed. But you could add an annotation with an appearance that serves as a watermark

Comment: Can you provide me the example link for creating annotation that serves as a watermark?  TIA

Comment: Have you had a look at the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57843823/1729265)?